# git stash unable to apply the changes saved

Tags: git, git-stash

I tried saving a git state using : git stash save changes_1.
I can see the stash list using: git stash list

But when I try to apply the stash using: git stash apply stash@{0}.
Now, I cannot see any changes are getting updated with git diff. and it is showing the message "Already uptodate!"

So, in short git stash is not able to apply the changes saved.
Any help.

Comment: Can you post the output of `git stash list` and `git status`?

Comment: I think most likely, I have done some mistake to endup like this. Any way I remember those changes and manually coded them...Thanks for your help. Voting myself to close this question

Answer (score 5):

This happens when a stash was applied previously or applying it does nothing e.g. current branch already has those changes. Consider the following scenario:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index e69de29..9daeafb 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+test

 $ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: b1d46d2 test.txt
HEAD is now at b1d46d2 test.txt
```

Now we re-add that line by hand and commit it:

```
 $ git diff
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index e69de29..9daeafb 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+test

 $ git commit -a
[master 8efb415] test.txt
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

 $ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: b1d46d2 test.txt

 $ git stash apply stash@{0}
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Here `git stash apply` does nothing.

Comment: 1. $ git stash list

2. $ git stash apply stash@{0}

{0} as per your stash list

Answer (score 2):

Try git status -s to see if the changes are there.

If they are there you are all set, if not use git stash list and make sure your saved stash is at index 0. If you try to apply a stash that has changes that are already part of the working branch it will be already up to date.

If you wanted you could reset your current branch to the last commit. Git reset --hard HEAD and then try to apply that stash again. Care as all current changes not stashed and commits not pushed will be lost.